# How to uninstall mongodb compass from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, mongodb

i am using **ubuntu 18.04**

Last day i install **MongoDB Compass** accoroding to official doc [compass install](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/install/)

But some reason i need to uninstall **MongoDB Compass** from my pc. 
I do some online research but do not find anything. All i find is how to uninstall **mongodb**

can anyone please help me how to uninstall **MongoDB Compass**  from **Ubuntu 18.04**

Answer (score 4):

Try with the command

```
$sudo dpkg --remove mongodb-compass
```

then restart the comoputer

Answer (score 3):

try this one `sudo dpkg --remove mongodb-compass`

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg --remove mongodb-compass-community
```

Comment: Why do you think this command can help?